# C, Converting nibbles from input to Hex

Tags: c

I am being asked to create a program that takes user input of 4 binary digits and output the appropriate hexadecimal equivalent. I have created the skeleton to my code, however when I give the program input, it echoes back to me my input. My assumption is that my call to my function is wrong? But i'm not exactly sure how it is. Any insight will help.

Also, function I created must be in its own separate file and I cannot use library functions. I also cannot include my other file as a source file, I just have to use a prototype? is what I was told. I am compiling on terminal. I know the way I'm going about determining which Hex it is lengthy and their are much better ways, but I just want to fix my issues first.

I will include my code, and if anyone needs clarification on the rules assigned I can edit afterwards.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char nibbleToHex(char nibble[]);

int main(void) {
char nibble[5];

scanf("%4s", nibble);
//printf("This is a test line.\nYou entered: %4s.",nibble);
nibbleToHex(nibble);
printf("%4s\n", nibble);

return 0;
}


/**
 * This file contains the function nibbleToHex().
 *
 * @author:     Dominic Fanucchi
 * Course:      COMP B13
 * Created on:  Sep 4, 2018
 * Source File: nibbleToHex.c
 */

/**
 * Translates the input string of 4 ASCII zeroes and ones in nibble,
 * to the corresponding hexadecimal digit and returns that digit.
 *
 * @param nibble A C-nibble of 4 ones and zeroes
 * @return the corresponding hexadecimal digit
 */

#include <stdio.h>

char nibbleToHex(char nibble[]) {
char nibbleReturn;

if (nibble[0] == '0') {
    if (nibble[1] == '0') {
        if (nibble[2] == '0') {
            if (nibble[3] == '0')
                nibbleReturn = '0';
        }
    }
}

if (nibble[0] == '0') {
    if (nibble[1] == '0') {
        if (nibble[2] == '0') {
            if (nibble[3] == '1')
                nibbleReturn = '1';
        }
    }
}

if (nibble[0] == '0') {
    if (nibble[1] == '0') {
        if (nibble[2] == '1') {
            if (nibble[3] == '0')
                nibbleReturn = '2';
        }
    }
}

if (nibble[0] == '0') {
    if (nibble[1] == '0') {
        if (nibble[2] == '1') {
            if (nibble[3] == '1')
                nibbleReturn = '3';
        }
    }
}

if (nibble[0] == '0') {
    if (nibble[1] == '1') {
        if (nibble[2] == '0') {
            if (nibble[3] == '0')
                nibbleReturn = '4';
        }
    }
}

if (nibble[0] == '0') {
    if (nibble[1] == '1') {
        if (nibble[2] == '0') {
            if (nibble[3] == '1')
                nibbleReturn = '5';
        }
    }
}

if (nibble[0] == '0') {
    if (nibble[1] == '1') {
        if (nibble[2] == '1') {
            if (nibble[3] == '0')
                nibbleReturn = '6';
        }
    }
}

if (nibble[0] == '0') {
    if (nibble[1] == '1') {
        if (nibble[2] == '1') {
            if (nibble[3] == '1')
                nibbleReturn = '7';
        }
    }
}

if (nibble[0] == '1') {
    if (nibble[1] == '0') {
        if (nibble[2] == '0') {
            if (nibble[3] == '0')
                nibbleReturn = '8';
        }
    }
}

if (nibble[0] == '1') {
    if (nibble[1] == '0') {
        if (nibble[2] == '0') {
            if (nibble[3] == '1')
                nibbleReturn = '9';
        }
    }
}

if (nibble[0] == '1') {
    if (nibble[1] == '0') {
        if (nibble[2] == '1') {
            if (nibble[3] == '0')
                nibbleReturn = 'A';
        }
    }
}

if (nibble[0] == '1') {
    if (nibble[1] == '0') {
        if (nibble[2] == '1') {
            if (nibble[3] == '1')
                nibbleReturn = 'B';
        }
    }
}

if (nibble[0] == '1') {
    if (nibble[1] == '1') {
        if (nibble[2] == '0') {
            if (nibble[3] == '0')
                nibbleReturn = 'C';
        }
    }
}

if (nibble[0] == '1') {
    if (nibble[1] == '1') {
        if (nibble[2] == '0') {
            if (nibble[3] == '1')
                nibbleReturn = 'D';
        }
    }
}

if (nibble[0] == '1') {
    if (nibble[1] == '1') {
        if (nibble[2] == '1') {
            if (nibble[3] == '0')
                nibbleReturn = 'E';
        }
    }
}

if (nibble[0] == '1') {
    if (nibble[1] == '1') {
        if (nibble[2] == '1') {
            if (nibble[3] == '1')
                nibbleReturn = 'F';
        }
    }
}

return nibbleReturn;
}
```

Comment: I fill sick when I see main(void)

Comment: If you see a repeating structure like your nested if's, there's usually a better way to do it.  A first step would replace the nested `if` with a single `if` using the `&&` operator to connect conditions.  The `&&` operator short-circuits; if the term on the left side evaluates to false, the following expression won't be evaluated.  But you can do more to reduce the code after that.

Comment: @purec: The code contains `int main(void)` — is that not OK according to you?  It _is_ one of the two forms specified by the C standard.  (See [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/).

Comment: There are more important things for you to care than main(void)

Comment: Sorry! I did not see that I left it main(void). I have actually changed it to main(int argc, char **argv).

Comment: Consider `int nbits; char nibble[5]; if (scanf(" %4[01]%n", nibble, &nbits) != 1 || nbits != 4) { …erroneous input… }`.

Comment: Nothing wrong with main(void) but it looks like trend for noobs. Sorry for the offtopic.

Comment: If you don't use `argc` or `argv` in `main`, then `int main(void)` is better — far better!  And `int main()` vs `int main(void)` is tricky, but the first doesn't provide a prototype for `main()` whereas the second does.  This only really matters if you ever call `main()` recursively — and most people don't because they're sane.  However, with `int main()` you could write `return main("absolute", "twaddle", 2.1254);` and the compiler couldn't complain, whereas with `int main(void)` (or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`), it would complain.  Use `int main(void)`. (Note: C++ differs from C here!)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use the input *string* to convert to an integer value using base 2 (using e.g. [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol)). Then it's easy to convert that integer value to a character corresponding to the hexadecimal value.

Perhaps something like this:

```
char nibbleToHex(char *nibble)
{
    int value = strtol(nibble, NULL, 2);

    if (value < 10)
        return value + '0';  // Return a character from '0' to '9'
    else
        return value + 'A';  // Works with ASCII encoding, not portable
}
```

With the `strtol` function you can also add some validation that the input is correct.

---

If you're not allowed to use standard functions (except the input/output functions) then you can use a loop and use bitwise shift and addition.

First of all remember that all strings in C are terminated, which means if the user doesn't enter all four digits you can still loop by checking for the terminator in your condition instead of hard-coding four iterations.

Secondly I still recommend you create an integer value instead of a character directly. Mostly because it's easier.

Then for the actual code:

```
char nibbleToHex(char *nibble)
{
    int value = 0;  // The value we construct

    // Loop while the character nibble points to is not the terminator
    while (*nibble != '\0')
    {
        value <<= 1;  // Left-shift one bit
        value += *nibble - '0';  // Add the digit

        ++nibble;  // Point to the next character
    }

    if (value < 10)
        return value + '0';  // Return a character from '0' to '9'
    else
        return value + 'A';  // Works with ASCII encoding, not portable
}
```

Comment: I would use strtol, however I cannot include any library functions within my code.

Comment: @D.Fanucchi Updated with an alternative solution

Answer (score 1):

To just answer your question: you are just not using the result of your calculation.

Write:

```
char result = nibbleToHex(nibble);
printf("%c\n", result);
```

BTW: The implementation contains a lot of repeating/similar code blocks. Using loops might reduce the amount of code a lot.

Comment: This worked! I see what I was doing wrong, and now I can concentrate on simplifying my repeated code.